# How to remove artifacts from an ambient occlusion bake

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texture-baking

This object has had some weirdness with its faces for a while that I've never been able to track down. There are no double vertices and the normals are fine. There are no rips between faces. There *were*, but I fixed them. But when I bake ambient occlusion, a bunch of strange things show up.

[image: odd diagonal shadows in baked image texture]

[image: shadows in flat areas for no reason]

What should I do about this?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Well the issue is in overlapping faces.

First, the solidify modifier. When you press bake witch face will project: internal or external? In the place on your screenshot - external.

But even worse, if you disable the solidify modifier you will get same problems, becouse you have overlapping faces in UV-layout also.

This gif shows the overlapping faces:

[image]

Comment: There is no sign of those extra faces on the actual mesh, so how do I get rid of them?

Comment: Its somehow outta topic but ... how U made those GIFs fellas?

Comment: @JanMatys I'm on a Linux system and I use Peek https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/a/964/7548

Comment: Alright, i deleted the solidify modifier as it isn't really needed here and it was a source of issues. Also I deleted the UV map and regenerated it and the extra faces disappeared.